# System.TimeoutException in WCF service C#

Tags: c#, wcf, timeout

I have a problem with my WCF service. I'm getting thw following exception after the program runs three hours perfectly.

> ```
> System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9843998. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout
> ```

I do not think that increasing the timeout would be a solution. I think the just would throw the exception a couple of minutes later. Maybe I have to change any settings on my listener server. Could it be that my machine close the port after a certain period of time? 
I call my service like that:

```
IServices service = null;
                    service = ChannelFactory<IServices>.CreateChannel(
                        new BasicHttpBinding(),
                        new EndpointAddress(
                        port));
                    result = service.addAppointments(appList);
```

My listener:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(service);
                    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(
                            IServices),
                            new BasicHttpBinding(), port);
                    host.Open();
```

Thats all. No further settings were required up to now.

Comment: Show us how you call this service and how it gets a reply.

Comment: Are you looking for an asynchronous server call? Fire and forget?

Comment: In my case a synchronous solution would be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can add through config the tracer for WCF. This will help you to find out where the problem is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx